# Sticky service not restarting on OnePlus 2

Tags: android, networking, service, background-process, oneplustwo

I have a background service that handles network traffic for my app. The service returns START_STICKY and it works perfectly (restarts after app is swiped) on Emulated Google Pixel (Android 7.1.1) and on a physical Motorola G4 (Android 7.0).

However, when I test the same app on my OnePlus 2 (Android 6.0.1 - my main driver), the service just disappears when the app is swiped away without any trace or restart attempt...

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: some devices have a battery saver feature which disables the services from restarting and/or even enable background services to work after the user has closed the application. mainly are xiamoi and huawei. 
try to search this feature in the battery settings

Comment: I tried searching setting for something to help, but I'm still confused as to how major apps (WhatsApp, Instagram, Viber etc.) are able to normally send notifications whereas my phone just disregards my app completely

I switched to Firebase Cloud Messaging in high hopes since writing this post, but my OnePlus still doesn't receive any background notifications...